# how to parse string returned by the web service in Android?

Tags: android

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <NewDataSet> 
     <myTable> 
         <USERNAME>admin</USERNAME> 
         <PASSWORD>123</PASSWORD> 
     </myTable> 
     <myTable> 
        <USERNAME>John</USERNAME>
        <PASSWORD>678</PASSWORD> 
     </myTable> 
    </NewDataSet>
  </string>
```

how to parse this string which returned from web service in android?

Comment: What do you want to do?  What are you trying to get out of it?

Comment: You should be more especific. For example : 

Give the string that the server is returning to your android app.
Give the "information" that you want in that string.

Comment: Read [Parsing XML Data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)

Comment: without parsing, ı see in emulator like this:   <USERNAME>John</USERNAME>   <PASSWORD>678</PASSWORD>

Comment: but ı want to see like that :: john 678        ı want to split this string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlRecords));

    Document doc = db.parse(is);
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
      Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

      NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("name");
      Element line = (Element) name.item(0);
      System.out.println("Name: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));

      NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("title");
      line = (Element) title.item(0);
      System.out.println("Title: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
    }

  }

  public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
    Node child = e.getFirstChild();
    if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
      CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
      return cd.getData();
    }
    return "";
  }
}
```

Comment: hope it helps :-). Don't forget to accept the answers when they help!